# What are the first 8 bytes in a C# byte[] and how do I skip them in Visual Studio's memory window?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have the following simple test code:

```csharp
List<byte> test = new List<byte>();
for (int i = 0; i <= 0xFF; i++)
{
    test.Add((byte)i);
}
byte[] testAsArray = test.ToArray();
```

I break after that last line. In the locals window in Visual Studio the array testAsArray starts as I would expect with testAsArray[0] equal to 0x00. But when I open Visual Studio's memory window and type `testArray` into the address box this is what I see:

[image: vs memory window screenshot]

Before the start of the expected byte sequence I have eight other bytes, i.e. the memory in the location testArray starts

> 30 72 12 04 00 01 00 00
>   00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07
>   08 09 0a 0b 0c 0d 0e 0f
>   …

What are the leading eight bytes? What expression would I need to type into the memory window's address box to go directly to the head of the actual byte array?

Comment: Maybe this might help: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3467/Arrays-UNDOCUMENTED

Comment: Do you really want to dive into implementation details? What you was trying to do when you opened `Memory` window? Why? If you would really want to know what you are asking the question would be [different](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11219041/1997232).

Comment: I want to know is how to look at a byte[] in the memory window. Will I always have to skip 8 bytes or does that implementation overhead differ in length with different byte arrays? I'm debugging some web socket code that's failing to parse and so am spending a lot of time staring at the beginnings and ends of byte arrays.

Comment: Why do you look into "Memory" window for this? Why not observing array values in `Watch`, `Local` or even `Auto` window? You can right click and choose " display as hexadecimal" there if that is the problem.

Comment: @Sinatr so I can scan large blocks of bytes easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your example is from a 32 bit system?

what you see are:

- 4 bytes for Object Header Word and
- 4 bytes for Method Table Pointer

On a 64-bit system, a word/pointer is 8 bytes instead of 4 and are aligned to 8-byte "grids"

Comment: Thanks. If I change the build target to x64 there are indeed 16 bytes before the byte array starts. So I can reliably discount the first 8 for x86 builds and the first 16 for x64 builds.